# The bodies have been (were) sent to hospital: difference in meaning

Tags: past-tense, british-english, present-perfect

> *The bodies **have been sent** to hospital for post-mortem examination.*
>
> *The bodies **was sent** to hospital for post-mortem examination.*

What is the difference between them?

Reference: [Stomp](http://singaporeseen.stomp.com.sg/singaporeseen/this-urban-jungle/nephew-of-spore-billionare-dies-in-kl-porsche-crash-just-hours-after-winning-race)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second is  ungrammatical. It should be *The bodies were sent to the hospital.*

The difference between the first and the corrected second sentences is that the present perfect in the first suggests some present relevance of the sending; the second merely locates the sending in the past.

In the newspaper article you linked us to, the detective is speaking of a very recent action, and suggesting that the bodies are still at thei destination.

Comment: If the bodies _have been_ sent to the hospital, they may or may not have arrived yet.  If the bodies _were_ sent to the hospital they should be there by now.  If they haven't yet arrived, then something may have gone wrong along the way.